# Assert IEnumerables

Tags: c#, unit-testing

As unit testing is not used in our firm, I'm teaching myself to unit test my own code.
I'm using the standard .net test framework for some really basic unit testing.

A method of mine returns a `IEnumerable<string>` and I want to test it's output.
So I created an `IEnumerable<string>` expected to test it against.
I thought I remembered there to be a way to `Assert.ArePartsEqual` or something like that, but I can't seem to find it.

So in short, how do I test if two `IEnumerable<string>` contain the same strings?

Comment: +1 for the good attitude and professionalism :)

Comment: He:P That's one of the better compliments a junior programmer can get ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't know which "standard .net test framework" you're referring to, but if it's Visual Studio Team System Unit testing stuff you could use [CollectionAssert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx).

Your test would be like this:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(ExpectedList, ActualList, "...");
```

**Update:** I forgot CollectionAssert needs an ICollection interface, so you'll have to call ActualList.ToList() to get it to compile. Returning the IEnumerable is a good thing, so don't change that just for the tests.

Comment: Which takes an ICollection, not an IEnumerable... so you'd need to push it into a collection too...

Comment: Also, if you don't care about the order, there's `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent`.

Answer (score 13):

You want the [`SequenceEqual()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-5.0) extension method (LINQ):

```
    string[] x = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
    List<string> y = new List<string>() { "abc", "def", "ghi" };

    bool isTrue = x.SequenceEqual(y);
```

or just:

```
   bool isTrue = x.SequenceEqual(new[] {"abc","def","ghi"});
```

(it will return false if they are different lengths, or any item is different)

Comment: So to translate it to something for the unit testing I could go Assert.IsTrue(result.SequenceEqual(expected));
This doesn't supply a helpfull message, but it gets me there so that's ok.

Comment: @boris: It would be really easy to translate my (currently NUnit-based) code to the MS version. Then you get a nice message.

Comment: Yes, I had a look at it. I am currently a bit locked in in timing to experiment with unit testing as I'm doing it kind of unrequested (see OP). But I will try to squeeze in some of that.

Answer (score 5):

I have an example of this I used for my "Implementing LINQ to Objects in 60 minutes" talk.

It also in my [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) project. Having tried to c'n'p it in here, it wraps horribly. Just [grab from Github](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq.Test/TestExtensions.cs)...

Comment: Google Code link broken, here's one that works: https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq.Test/TestExtensions.cs

Comment: @vvnurmi: Ah, the joys of converting from svn to hg :) Will edit the link.

Comment: Moved to github: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq.Test/TestExtensions.cs

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple but not obvious way to do this with NUnit 3+ 'constraint' assertions:

```
Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expected).AsCollection, "My failure message");
```

This will give you the same as the linq mentioned in other answers:

```
Assert.That(result.SequenceEqual(expected), "My failure message");
```

But the `AsCollection` version will tell you where the first difference is, and if the lengths are different.

See https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/EqualConstraint.html#comparing-arrays-collections-and-ienumerables