# Testing a function that returns IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Could someone guide me how to write a test for a method that  returns Ienumerable ?

Here's my method -

```
public  IEnumerable<string> fetchFiles()
{ 
   IOWrapper ioWrapper = new IOWrapper();
   var files = ioWrapper.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
   return files;
}
```

I've just started learning about unit-tests. So I would really appreciate if someone explains me how to go about it.

Comment: Your code isn't strictly testable as you have a hard wired dependency on IOWrapper. You need to inject this through your constructor and make it mockable. Your unit test can then test a single unit of code, and not your dependencies.

Comment: @TheCodeKing - I do get what you're saying about the dependency on IOWrapper. But could you please explain what you mean by "injecting this through your constructor and making it mockable" ?

Comment: Added more detail below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some testing framework. You can use MS Test embedded in Visual Studio - add a new Test project to your solution. Or you can use, for instance, NUnit which I am using.

```
[TestFixture] // NUnit attribute for a test class
public class MyTests
{
    [Test] // NUnit attribute for a test method
    public void fetchFilesTest() // name of a method you are testing + Test is a convention
    {
        var files = fetchFiles();

        Assert.NotNull(files); // should pass if there are any files in a directory
        Assert. ... // assert any other thing you are sure about, like if there is a particular file, or specific number of files, and so forth
    }
}
```

For a complete list of possible asserts in NUnit navigate [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=assertions&r=2.2.6). Also thanks to user xxMUROxx for pointing out the [CollectionAssert](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.6.3) class.

Additionaly, for test methods with many lines you would probably want it to be readable, so search for "Arrange Act Assert (AAA) Pattern" on the internet.

One more thing, there is already one question about testing IEnumerables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545671/assert-ienumerables?rq=1) on SO.

Comment: `.ToList()` of Linq never returns null. It will throw `ArgumentNullException` if its source is null. So test something else.

Comment: In Nunit there is a [CollectionAssert](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.6.3) class. With that you can test your collection

Comment: you could do `var files = fetchFiles();`, check for "not null", and then call `.ToList()` to check for other things.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Yes, I am just trying to convince SO to let me edit my answer. It is so slow this morning. Or my internet connection is failing.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Thanks. How can I check what went wrong if a test fails. For example when I do, CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected.ToList(),actual.ToList());, I get a Fail message saying "Different number of elements". Is there a way I can see what elements are in actual.list() ?

Comment: If you are using NUnit, there is a Unit Test Session tab with an Output window which shows you what is wrong.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek - It looks like as said by TheCodeKing, FetchFiles() has a  dependency on IOWrapper. And maybe that's the reason it's failing the test. He mentioned about "inject this through your constructor and make it mockable." If possible could you update what it means in your answer ?

Comment: Sorry, my answer should not be that complex. **By rules of SO, question should not be to broad.** You have to ask another question. What you are requesting is to explain you mocking. First, read about it something on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

To make the code more testable inject `IOWrapper` as a dependency. You can make it mockable by declaring an interface on `IOWrapper` or by making the methods virtual. During your test you can then inject the mock instead of the concrete instance and make your test a true unit test.

```
public class CSVFileFinder
{
    private readonly IOWrapper ioWrapper;

    private readonly string folderPath;

    public CSVFileFinder(string folderPath)
        : this(new IOWrapper(), folderPath)
    {  
    }

    public CSVFileFinder(IOWrapper ioWrapper, string folderPath)
    {
        this.ioWrapper = ioWrapper;
        this.folderPath = folderPath;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> FetchFiles()
    {
        return this.ioWrapper.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
}
```

Here's an example unit tests that verifies the result of `IOWrapper` is returned from `GetFiles`. This is written using `Moq` and `NUnit`.

```
[TestFixture]
public class FileFinderTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Given_csv_files_in_directory_when_fetchFiles_called_then_return_file_paths_success()
    {
        // arrange
        var inputPath = "inputPath"; 
        var testFilePaths = new[] { "path1", "path2" };
        var mock = new Mock<IOWrapper>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.GetFiles(inputPath, It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<SearchOption>()))
            .Returns(testFilePaths).Verifiable();

        var testClass = new CSVFileFinder(mock.Object, inputPath);

        // act
        var result = testClass.FetchFiles();

        // assert
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(testFilePaths));
        mock.VerifyAll();
    }
}
```

You could then add tests for edge conditions like exception getting thrown by IOWrapper or no files returned etc. `IOWrapper` is tested in isolation with it's own set of tests.