# IEnumerable interface TDD using Mock in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, tdd, moq

Below is the FizzBuzz Generation Code,

```
public class BusinessHandler : IBusinessHandler
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IBusinessRule> BusinessRule;

    public BusinessHandler(IEnumerable<IBusinessRule> businessrule)
    {
        this.BusinessRule = businessrule;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetResult(int inputValue)
    {
        var outputList = new List<string>();

        for (int element = 1; element <= inputValue; element++)
        {
            string tempOutput = element.ToString();

            var divisionResult = this.BusinessRule.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsDivisible(element));

            if (divisionResult != null)
            {
                tempOutput = divisionResult.PrintOutput();
            }

            outputList.Add(tempOutput);

        }

        return outputList;
    }
}
```

Here IBusinessHandler, IBusinessRule are the interface. Using Dependency Injection, i am calling this method in my web application.

**IBusinessRule :**

```
public interface IBusinessRule
{
    bool IsDivisible(int inputValue);

    string PrintOutput();
}
```

3 classes are implementing IBusinessRule interface.

I am new to TDD, how can I implement unit test for `GetResult()` method.
For TDD i am using Nunit,Moq packages.

Comment: show definition of `IBusinessRule`

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923640/testing-a-function-that-returns-ienumerablestring for example of how to unit test an IEnumerable<string>

Answer (score 0):

A test for the provided code can look like this

```
[TestClass]
public class BusinessHandlerTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void BusinessHandler_Should_GetResult() {
        //Arrange
        var fizz = new Mock<IBusinessRule>();
        fizz.Setup(_ => _.IsDivisible(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns((int value) => value % 3 == 0);
        fizz.Setup(_ => _.PrintOutput()).Returns("Fizz");

        var buzz = new Mock<IBusinessRule>();
        buzz.Setup(_ => _.IsDivisible(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns((int value) => value % 5 == 0);
        buzz.Setup(_ => _.PrintOutput()).Returns("Buzz");

        var fizzbuzz = new Mock<IBusinessRule>();
        fizzbuzz.Setup(_ => _.IsDivisible(It.IsAny<int>()))
                .Returns((int value) => value % 15 == 0);
        fizzbuzz.Setup(_ => _.PrintOutput()).Returns("FizzBuzz");

        var businessRule = new[] { 
            fizzbuzz.Object, fizz.Object, buzz.Object  // <--order is important
        }; 
        var subject = new BusinessHandler(businessRule);
        var inputValue = 15;
        var expected = new[] { "1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7", "8", "Fizz", "Buzz", "11", "Fizz", "13", "14", "FizzBuzz" };

        //Act
        var actual = subject.GetResult(inputValue);

        //Assert
        actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
    }
}
```

Assuming the business rules have not already been defined, they can be mocked and injected into the subject under test, as demonstrated above.

If for example the classes already existed

```
public class FizzObject : IBusinessRule {
    public bool IsDivisible(int inputValue) => inputValue % 3 == 0;

    public string PrintOutput() => "Fizz";
}
```

then they can be initialized

```
var businessRule = new[] { new FizzBuzzObject(), new FizzObject(), new BuzzObject() }; // <--order is important
```

and injected into the subject under test with the same expected behavior

Comment: I wanted without implementing  conditions in return value

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by that last comment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need mocks for testing "FizzBuzz".
As you said you have 3 implementations of `IBusinessRule`

```
public class RuleOne : IBusinessRule { ... }
public class RuleTwo : IBusinessRule { ... }
public class RuleThree : IBusinessRule { ... }
```

Then you can write test which cover whole logic. With this kind of test you will test `BusinessHandler` and all implementations of `IBusinessRule` will be tested as well.
With this test you will have freedom to redesign how `BusinessHandler` implemented (possibly need to change only constructor)

```
// Here used NUnit feature of TestCase to provide values to the test function
[Test]
[TestCase(1, new[] { "1" })]
[TestCase(3, new[] { "Fizz" })]
[TestCase(5, new[] { "Buzz" })]
[TestCase(15, new[] { "Fizz", "Buzz" })]
[TestCase(20, new[] { "20" })]
public void ShouldReturnExpectedResult(int input, string[] expected)
{
    // Arrange
    var rules = new[]
    {
        new RuleOne();
        new RuleTwo();
        new RuleThree();
    }

    var handler = new BusinessHandler(rules);

    // Act
    var actual = handler.GetResult(input);

    // Assert
    actual.Should().BeEquivalent(expected);
}
```